# NuxtJS/Vue3: V-for with async api data not working properly (TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am currently working on a vue 3 project together with typescript.

I have an api, that sends me an array of objects containing the details of each server.

I have a script file under /server/api/serverData.ts that fetches me this data

```
//we want to fetch asnyc
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  //fetch from uri using $fetch from nuxt
  const data = await $fetch("https://game.aq3d.com/api/game/ServerList");
  //return data
  return data;
});
```

Here is an example output

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "SortIndex": 1,
    "Name": "Red Dragon",
    "HostName": "nextdragon.aq3d.com",
    "Port": 5594,
    "UserCount": 754,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-12-30T15:22:00",
    "Connections": 737,
    "GEMQueueLength": 2484,
    "AlertLevel": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "Region": "NA"
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "SortIndex": 16,
    "Name": "Localhost",
    "HostName": "localhost",
    "Port": 5591,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-07-01T15:48:00",
    "AccessLevel": 100,
    "AlertLevel": -1,
    "Status": 0,
    "Region": "NA"
  },
  {
    "ID": 7,
    "SortIndex": 4,
    "Name": "Blue Dragon",
    "HostName": "game.dragon.aq3d.com",
    "Port": 5594,
    "UserCount": 180,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-12-30T15:22:00",
    "Connections": 178,
    "AlertLevel": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "Region": "NA"
  },
  {
    "ID": 10,
    "SortIndex": 7,
    "Name": "Black Dragon",
    "HostName": "game.dragon.aq3d.com",
    "Port": 5593,
    "UserCount": 1,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-12-30T15:22:00",
    "AccessLevel": 100,
    "Connections": 1,
    "AlertLevel": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "Region": "NA"
  },
  {
    "ID": 11,
    "SortIndex": 8,
    "Name": "Green Dragon  [EU]",
    "HostName": "nextdragon.aq3d.com",
    "Port": 5590,
    "UserCount": 128,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-12-30T15:22:00",
    "Connections": 123,
    "AlertLevel": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "Region": "EU"
  },
  {
    "ID": 12,
    "SortIndex": 9,
    "Name": "Gold Dragon [SEA]",
    "HostName": "nextdragon.aq3d.com",
    "Port": 5591,
    "UserCount": 57,
    "MaxUsers": 900,
    "State": true,
    "Chat": true,
    "Language": "en",
    "IP": "",
    "LocalIP": "",
    "LastUpdated": "2022-12-30T15:22:00",
    "Connections": 55,
    "AlertLevel": 1,
    "Status": 1,
    "Region": "AS"
  }
]
```

I have a Player Info component under /Player/Info.vue with properties

```
<script setup lang="ts">
interface PlayerProps {
    serverName: string;
    playerAmount: number;
    // maxPlayer: number;
    // connections: number;
}

const props = defineProps<PlayerProps>();


</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Player Information</h1>
        <h2>{{ serverName }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ playerAmount }}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

I use it inside my app.vue inside the root dir like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const servers = ref<any>([]);
const apiData = await useFetch('/api/serverData')


//assign apiData to apiRef
servers.value = apiData
console.log(servers.value)


</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>AQ3D Server Status Infos</h1>
    <PlayerInfo  v-for="(server, index) in servers" :serverName="Name" :playerAmount="UserCount" />
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: how it looks]

As you can see, it is not showing the data from the json I receive.
I tried tried to use the v-for differently, but this gave me only errors.

What did I miss - is my approach with the ref even current?
I basically just wanna iterate over my component for each server object inside the array like so

ServerName
PlayerAmount

ServerName
PlayerAmount

...

Comment: You can see in the console that api data is not data but fetch result. daa is supposed to be available in `data` propertyy

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `:serverName="server.Name"` etc...?

Comment: I found the solutions: Instead of using ```v-for="(server, index) in servers"``` I tried to use ```v-for="(server, index) in servers.value"``` and now it works